# When we are getting error like: "Rejected by filter, soap fault sent" in datapower?

Tags: ibm-datapower

Could any please help me at which situation we are getting the following error in datapower
 "Rejected by filter, soap fault sent"

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error in any service where the Processing Policy or service processing throws an error.
It is a generic error response that does not indicate any error reason. You will need to examine the logs to find out the reason for the error.